Can we unify these two "pullback" functors?
Okay, my question initially is about (one-sorted) algebraic theories (/abstract clones/Lawvere theories) and their algebras. However, for the sake of familiarity, let's pretend it is about rings and modules. Note that we can do the same for monoids or groups, together with sets with a monoid/group action. So this is a pattern that occurs in more than one category.
If we have a ring morphism $ f: R \to S $, we get a pullback functor, called "restriction of scalars" $ f^*: \mathrm{Mod}_S \to \mathrm{Mod}_R $. On the other hand, if we consider any object in the coslice category $ (S, f): (R \downarrow \mathrm{Ring}) $, we can give $ S $ an $ S $-module structure, and then pull it back along $ f $, to get $ f^* S: \mathrm{Mod}_R $. This, as it turns out, is functorial in $ (S, f) $, so we have a functor $ (R \downarrow \mathrm{Ring}) \to \mathrm{Mod}_R $.
My question is: It seems that neither of these functors is a special case of the other. So are they special cases of a slightly bigger structure? Can we unify them into one structure?
I tried the following:

Take the category $ \mathrm{Mod} $, of dependent pairs $ (R, M) $ with $ R $ a ring and $ M $ an $ R $-module. Morphisms from $ (R, M) $ to $ (R^\prime, M^\prime) $ in this category are pairs $ (f, g) $, with $ f: R \to R^\prime $ a ring morphism and $ g: M \to f^* M^\prime $ an $ R $-module morpism.
Consider the coslice category $ ((R, R) \downarrow \mathrm{Mod}) $.
We have a functor from this category to $ \mathrm{Mod}_R $, sending $ ((R, M), (f, g)) $ to $ f^* M $.
The two functors above arise by precomposing this functor with the embeddings of $ \mathrm{Mod}_S $ and $ (R \downarrow \mathrm{Ring}) $ into $ \mathrm{Mod} $.

However, the occurrence of $ (R, R) $ feels a bit artificial (and we are very restrictive if we only can do this for $ (R, R) $), and we don't really use $ g $ (so it seems that we have too much information). Is there a better way to unify the functors? Or can we maybe get rid of $ (R, R) $ and  do this for general $ ((R, M) \downarrow \mathrm{Mod}) $ in a way that uses $ g $?
PS: Yes, I know that in this example, the second functor is in fact the forgetful functor from $ R $-algebras to $ R $-modules. This is trivial if you define $ R $-algebras as $ R $-modules with a ring structure, instead of objects in the coslice category. However, in the case of algebraic theories, this functor seems less trivial.

I'm not sure how this generalises from the setting of rings and modules to, say, monoids, or even general algebraic theories.

@NaïmFavier For a monoid morphism $ f: M \to N $ and a set $ S $ with an $ N $-action, we have a pullback $ f^* S $, which is a set with an $ M $-action (via restriction of scalars: the $ M $-action of an element $ m: M $ is the $ N $-action of an element $ f m : N $). We can also regard $ N $ itself as a set with an $ N $-action, so $ f^* N $ is a set with an $ M $-action. This gives a functor from the coslice category under $ M $ to sets with an $ M $-action.

So your second functor sends $f : M \to N$ to $f^* (A(N))$, where $A$ equips an algebraic thing with an action on itself? I'm not sure why you'd expect it to look like a pullback functor. In particular I'd expect pullback functors to be composable.

Hm, okay, then the second one is not really a pullback functor. But they still seem somewhat related, since they both pull back along a morphism.

Well, they are related in that one uses the other. The pulling back is always done by $f^*$ here.

I will try to shed some light on the phenomena involved in the situation you have observed, which will hopefully answer your question.
Let $\mathbb L$ be an algebraic theory. Then, as you observe, there is a functor $\mathbb L/\mathrm{AlgTh} \to \mathrm{Mod}(\mathbb L)$. Furthermore, this functor has a fully faithful left adjoint $\mathbb L_{({-})} \colon \mathrm{Mod}(\mathbb L) \hookrightarrow \mathbb L/\mathrm{AlgTh}$, where we view each model $M$ of $\mathbb L$ as determining a new theory $\mathbb L_M$ by adjoining the elements of $M(1)$ to $\mathbb L$ as new constants.
Furthermore, this adjunction is in fact an instance of the right adjoint $f^* \colon \mathrm{Mod}(\mathbb T) \to \mathrm{Mod}(\mathbb S)$ induced by any morphism $f \colon \mathbb S \to \mathbb T$ of algebraic theories. For this to make sense, we must observe that $\mathbb L/\mathrm{AlgTh}$ is itself the category of algebras for an algebraic theory. This follows from the combination of two facts: first, that $\mathrm{AlgTh}$ is the category of models for a multisorted algebraic theory (namely, the algebraic theory of abstract clones); and second, that algebraic categories (i.e. categories of models for algebraic theories) are closed under coslicing (by Theorem 4.9.5 of Arkor's Monadic and Higher-Order Structure). That the adjunction $\mathbb L/\mathrm{AlgTh} \rightleftarrows \mathrm{Mod}(\mathbb L)$ is then induced by a morphism of algebraic theories is stated (in slightly greater generality) in Theorem 4.9.13 ibid.
One other related fact is that, just as $f$ induces a right adjoint $f^* \colon \mathrm{Mod}(\mathbb T) \to \mathrm{Mod}(\mathbb S)$, so too does it induce a right adjoint $f/\mathrm{AlgTh} \colon \mathbb T/\mathrm{AlgTh} \to \mathbb S/\mathrm{AlgTh}$ (in fact, it is itself induced by a morphism of algebraic theories, between the algebraic theories whose categories of models are $\mathbb S/\mathrm{AlgTh}$ and $\mathbb T/\mathrm{AlgTh}$ respectively). This appears as Proposition 4.9.7 ibid. So, in this sense, the base change induced by coslicing $({-})/\mathrm{AlgTh}$ is subsumed by the base change induced by precomposition $({-})^*$.

If I understand you correctly, you mean that the functor (and adjunction) L / AlgTh -> Mod(L) is an instance of Mod(T) -> Mod(S), because the category L / AlgTh is equivalent to a category of models for some algebraic theory, right?

Can you shed a bit more light on the algebraicity of AlgTh? What does the algebraic theory look like, that has AlgTh as its models?

Regarding your first question: yes, that's correct (for particular $\mathbb T$ and $\mathbb S$). Regarding your second question: there is a $\mathbb N$-sorted algebraic theory whose models are abstract clones, where each sort $n \in \mathbb N$ denotes the number of variables in the context, where the operations are given by substitution and variable projection (this is essentially described on the Wikipedia article). The category of abstract clones is equivalent to the category of (monosorted) algebraic theories.

Similarly, for every set $S$, the category of $S$-sorted algebraic theories is the category of models for an $(S^* \times S)$-sorted algebraic theory (given by $S$-sorted abstract clones), in the same way as the monosorted setting. Here $S^$ denotes lists of elements of $S$, and so the elements of $S^ \times S$ denote sorted terms/operations in a sorted context.

Thanks! That explains it a bit.
